# Minimize content width

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I do not understand why my portfolio area is going full width. I would like that the row that contains 4 pictures, is staying inside the content area (red lines I marked):

[![Content area][1]][1]

I have tried everything that I know until now. In the developer tools I was trying to set a smaller width, but that did not work out. Does anybody have a suggestion on what I can do?

[Link to the testing page][2]

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your post itself, rather than linking to an external site.

Comment: You have only set a max-width for `.section-boxed` - but your element with the images is not inside that section, but just follows it.

Comment: Please keep your images and other elements inside the "section-boxed" div

Comment: You say you have tried everything you know - so tell us what that was.  Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should include a summary of what you have tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add class `section-boxed` to this `<div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12 section-boxed">`

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer. Do you have any idea of how I can find that line of html code in Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap your pictures container with a `div` with this class `section-boxed` and it will work.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer. Do you have any idea of how I can find that line of html code in Wordpress?

Comment: @NekMak use CTRL + F to search for that particular content or scroll and look with your eyes based on the structure of the page?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [aimenzenasni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3130019/aimenzenasni), adding the class to the div (highlighted below) will sort it. Verified in Chrome Developer Tools...

[Source Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2nNZ.png)

Comment: Thank you for the answer Gareth. Do you have an idea how I can edit that within Wordpress?